# FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '['

Tags: php

I am having a hard time working on this one. The shared server uses PHP 5.4 and returns and error.

I am using a tester that returns :

> FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '[' on line number 3

```
<?php
// This is the database connection configuration.
return [
    'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=languag2_lp',
    'emulatePrepare' => true,  
    'username' => 'languag2_lp',
    'password' => 'languag2_lp',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
];
```

any ideas please.. thanks!

Comment: Have you verified PHP Version via phpinfo() or phpversion()?

Comment: Apparently it doesn't run PHP5.4 - have you tried invoking `phpinfo()`?

Comment: tried removing the last comma?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
return array(
    'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=languag2_lp',    
    'emulatePrepare' => true,
    'username' => 'languag2_lp',  'password' => 'languag2_lp',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone.. the only issue was the comma on tbl_

That was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5.4 ,started supporting short style for array . 
Like as

```
<?php
$myArray = array(1,2,3,4);

 //or

 $myArray = [1,2,3,4];
```

May be your tested would be uses some lower version . Check the following code

```
<?php

return array(
'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=languag2_lp',
'emulatePrepare' => true,
'username' => 'languag2_lp', 'password' => 'languag2_lp',
'charset' => 'utf8',
'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_');
```

One more thing that after

```
'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
```

there should be no comma like this.

```
'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_'
```